# Confusion in one conditional probability expression

Tags: probability-theory

I see in a book the following :

$$\int Y(\omega) P(d\omega, X \in B) =  \int_{\{X \in B\}} Y(\omega) dP$$.

Why ? Does it uses fubini's theorem.

Comment: Horrible notations. Which book is this?

Comment: @Did: Breiman. Page 70

Comment: See below. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

The LHS is $\displaystyle\int_\Omega Y\,\mathrm dQ$ where $Q$ is the measure defined on $\mathcal F$ by
$$Q(A)=P(A,X\in B).$$ 
Thus, by definition, $\mathrm dQ=\mathbf 1_{X\in B}\,\mathrm dP$ and the LHS is also
$$
\int_\Omega Y\,\mathbf 1_{X\in B}\,\mathrm dP=\int_{\{X\in B\}}Y\mathrm dP.
$$
(But I am afraid $\mathrm dP$ on the RHS of the identity in your question should read either $\mathrm dP(\omega)$ or $P(\mathrm d\omega)$, or that $Y(\omega)$ should read $Y$.)